# Compile curl with openssl

Tags: openssl, curl

I'm trying to compile `curl` with `openssl` support and though I've tried for hours I still cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Here's what I did:

1. compile `openssl` like this:
   cd /usr/local/install/openssl-1.0.2a
   ./config 
   make 
   make install
2. try to compile `curl`

   cd /usr/local/install/curl-7.42.1 
   ./configure  --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/
   make

and I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a(s2_clnt.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Compiling curl seems to be the first thing you're doing wrong.

Comment: Please explain what operating system is this, why can't use the pre-compiled packages (which already have `openssl` support, e.g `ldd $(which curl) | grep ssl`) and what business or professional requirement do you have for a custom compilation.

Comment: @MichaelHampton why is that, could you please explain?

Comment: @dawud it is a Debian 6.0. I've been using the pre-compiled packages until now but when trying to connect to _some_ HTTPs URLs I received errors. There wasn't (or I couldn't find) any newer curl version for this Debian and I needed to compile a curl with a newer version of openssl so I can make it work.

Comment: If you're getting https errors, why are you trying to upgrade curl?

Comment: @MichaelHampton because curl uses an older version of openssl and because of that I get the errors when trying to download some images from https URLs. Does that make sense?

Comment: set LDFLAGS and set rpath before configure, e.g.  LDFLAGS="-L/opt/external/lib -Wl,-rpath=/opt/external/lib"

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to compile curl, this is what worked for me:
**openssl:**

```
./config -fPIC no-gost no-shared no-zlib
make depend
make
make install
```

**curl:**

```
./configure  --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl
make 
make install
```